# Keras loss increasing for each epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras for deep learning. I have 1860 samples for 3 classes. The loss is increasing during training. I already removed the dropouts.

**Model**

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=(480, 640, 3), use_bias=False))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

**Generator**

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
 optimizer=optimizers.sgd(),
 metrics=['acc'])

validation_dir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\validation_data'

train_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
 rescale=1. / 255,
 horizontal_flip=True)

validation_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
 train_dir,
 target_size=(480, 640),
 batch_size=20,
 class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
 validation_dir,
 target_size=(480, 640),
 batch_size=30,
 class_mode='categorical')

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(
 filepath=checkpoint_path,
 verbose=1,
 save_best_only=True)

model.fit_generator(
 train_generator,
 steps_per_epoch=93,
 epochs=35,
 validation_data=validation_generator,
 validation_steps=6,
 callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Loss is increasing and training takes really long. Iam not sure if my width and height are to big.

Comment: Try a different optimizer and especially a smaller than default learning rate. And what do you mean by *"training takes really long"*? Training takes as long as you decide to run it (if the loss increases then probably forever).

Comment: @a_guest Thanks for your answer. One epoch needs around 4 hours. Can you recommend a optimizer and a learning rate? Or try and error?

Comment: You can try Adam and learning rate somewhere between `1e-4` and `1e-5` (better start off small). Adding more batch norm layers might also help.

Comment: Do you normalize your data before feeding them into the model?

Comment: @desertnaut No, I am only using BatchNormalization as Layer.

Comment: @a_guest Seems to work! Maybe not perfect but better.

Comment: You should normalize your data *before* feeding them in